# namespaces in my asp.net code behind file does not creating

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I create an ASP.NET Web Forms application then the code behind .aspx.cs is not enclosed with a namespace but it just start from "Partial class" and therefore I cannot access data from other Web Forms .aspx.cs files.

I want to access some functions by just creating its class object or importing the namespace of particular .aspx.cs file.

**I manually added the namespaces but it shows me the errors.**

My project code behind file .aspx.cs is like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;   
using System.Web;    
using System.Web.UI;    
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

and .aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now how can I add namespaces to my project code behind files? Is there a need to change some Visual Studio settings?

Comment: You need to include the errors you're getting when you try to add the namespaces. Don't assume we know what errors you got. Also, you need to consider that if one page needs to call another's methods, then that's a giant red flag that you have a bad architecture. Each page should only be responsible for itself. Common code should be encapsulated elsewhere, such as a regular class file (not .aspx.cs) or in a user control (.ascx).

Answer (score 0):

ok thnx i added namespaces and fix the error like "....method, property etc does not exist in current context", but i have created .cs classes for database connection, data selection and data retrieving. it works fine but when i create a web form only .aspx and .aspx.cs files is creating. designer.aspx.cs is missing like namespace and now i have added some crystal reports which appeared in the same way only "crystalReport.rpt" file is creating other files like crystalReports.cs which contain some files is also missing. 
Now i need to preview the report while i cannot take object of CrystalReport.rpt because it invisible in webform from where i want to preview the report. 
i have done this all things for my report to include namespaces then it will work. ?? 
Now what i can do? thank u